# iPhone - webViewDidFinishLoad not called

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uiwebview, properties, interface-builder

I have a simple View into IB that contains just a UIWebView and a UIButton.
The webView is retained, connected, not nil, the delegate property os also connected, the Controller is `UIWebViewDelegate` compliant and set in the .h.
in ViewDidLoad, I use `[self.webView loadHTMLString:htmlContent baseURL:nil]`;

The content loads, but `webViewDidFinishLoad` is never triggered, neither `didFailLoadWithError`, neither `webViewDidStartLoad`.

**How can I know when my content has finished loading**, as it take a short time, but still a time to load (and I need to do things during that time on display, for an example not showing the button) ?

```
@interface MyController : UIViewController <UIWebViewDelegate> {
    UIWebView* webView;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWebView* webView;

@end


@implementation MyController

@synthesize webView;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

constructing the htmlString

id a = self.webView.delegate; // for debug
[self.webView loadHTMLString:htmlContent baseURL:nil];
}

@end
```

**EDIT :**
I've deleted the whole XIB and built it from scrathc : no more problem. IB sucks sometimes.

Comment: Is htmlcontent not nil? Show the code for how that is loaded.

Comment: Does shouldStartLoadWithRequest get called?

Comment: @logancautrell  : shouldStartLoadWithRequest is not called

Comment: Try deleting the uiwebview in the nib and resetting the delegate and outlets to it.

Comment: I can see that the deleagate is nil (in viewDidLoad), but it is connected into IB. I've tried to connect it again and again, but that does not change anything.

Comment: Make sure your ui viewcontrollet is adopting the uiwebviewdelegate protocol.

Comment: @logancautrell : already tried to delete the whole thing. Does not cure.

Comment: @logancautrell : That's what i've done. Can't accept it until tomorrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've deleted the whole XIB and built it again from scratch : no more problem. IB sucks sometimes.

Answer (score 3):

You need to implement the `UIWebViewDelegate` protocol in your class and set the delegate property of `self.webView = self`. You will need to implement non-optional delegate methods to the class, plus the `webViewDidFinishLoad`, `didFailLoadWithError` and `webViewDidStartLoad` methods.

Comment: Please see my edit, I though I was clear but I wasn't : delegate is connected.

Answer (score 1):

Just a sort of stab in the dark. As far as your code above is concerned, you still haven't set the responding object to the webView delegate, you have set a pointer to the webView delegate object but when the webView goes to respond to the delegate it will still be nil.

You should probably have: self.webView.delegate = a; but even then I don't know if that will work because I don't know what a is, is it the object that will respond to the delegate call backs?

Comment: as said in the question, the delegate is connected (ie into IB). id a is just here for testing purpose (ie for debug).

Answer (score -1):

You have to implement the `UIWebViewDelegate` protocol in your class and set `self.webView.delegate=self;`